# Confusion about macro expansion in C

Tags: c, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYNUMBER 123

int main()
{
  printf("%d", MYNUMBER456);
}
```

Above code doesn't work because `MYNUMBER` and `MYNUMBER456` are different token.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SECOND(a, b) printf(#a #b);
#define FIRST SECOND

int main()
{
  FIRST(hello, world!)
}
```

But this one works well. My thought is `FIRST` and `FIRST(hello, world!)` are different so it should not work. What am I missing?

Comment: My guess would be that `MAXNUMBER` and `MAXNUMBER456` are both valid identifiers, while `FIRST(` is not, and the compiler is able to tell that it should look at `FIRST` instead, which correctly matches the definition `FIRST` which is defined as `SECOND`, which matches `SECOND(a, b)`. It's just a guess, though, which is why I'm posting a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Since `FIRST` doesn't take any parameters, it is expanded to `SECOND` before the parameter list is even examined.  Then `SECOND` is expanded, which consumes the parameters and produces the `printf` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the macro expansion by using the -E option (cc -E main.c), though you will see a lot of other stuff inserted because of your #include <stdio.h>, and without it you will probable see some default stuff inserted, in your example the main function becomes

```
int main()
{
  printf("hello" "world!");
}
```

This is because you have defined FIRST to be the same as SECOND which takes two arguments and makes them strings and since there is no comma between them they get concatenated into a single string, macros are just string substitution, in C the preprocessing is traditionally handled by a seperate executable to the compiler and is not as sophisticated as a compiler, so the type matching you would expect in most languages doesn't apply to the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct `MYNUMBER` and `MYNUMBER456` are different and the pre-compiler wont know how to work with `MYNUMBER456`
however, when you defined `FIRST` as `SECOND` , the precompiler would expand `FIRST` by `SECOND` and then you actually have `SECOND` with 2 parameters so it it working